# Is there any evidence of racism from the US Supreme Court Justices who decided Plessy v. Ferguson (1896)?

Tags: united-states

I am trying to know more about the personal lives of the 8 Justices engaged in [*Plessy v. Ferguson* (1896)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plessy_v._Ferguson), and whether personal opinions (e.g. racism) might have affected their decision.

I did discover the following evidence of racism for 2 of the Justices:

[Edward Douglass White, Jr.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edward_Douglass_White#Political_career)  had joined two white supremacy organisations,
and 
[Justice John Marshall Harlan I](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plessy_v._Ferguson#Dissent) revealed his opposition to the Chinese directly in his dissent.

But what of the other 6?

Comment: It wouldn't surprise me to hear that [Justice Field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stephen_Johnson_Field#Career_in_California_politics_and_law) was the inspiration for the villain in Zorro.

Comment: You can find evidence for racism for pretty much everybody in the world in the past.  Or the present, for that matter, if you look hard enough.